# Looking for a standalone, command line, code generator script

Tags: code-generation, template-engine

I'm looking for a library or command line script that will allow me to create custom templates that I can generate from the command line. The ruby on rails scaffolding generator is almost identical to what I am trying to do. I would even prefer that it be written in Ruby (yet it cannot require Rails because I may not be using it on a Ruby application). What sorts of scripts like this are already available?

Answer (score 9):

I've also been on the lookout for something like this -- haven't found what I hoped for.  The two approaches I've used instead have been acceptable.  But I'm still hoping to find the real thing.

- obvious, but `sed` for simple use cases
- for medium-complexity use cases, if you can assume some version of Python is present on the machine, `string.Template` in the standard library works well.  You could write a small Python script that uses this function, and since it is Python, tests / looping etc. that might normally be provided by the template engine could pretty easily be handled in the Python code instead.
- I've just discovered Mustache (see http://mustache.github.io/).  Seems like a solid, purpose-built solution. From its web site, Mustache has implementations in Ruby, JavaScript, Python, Erlang, PHP, Perl, Objective-C, Java, .NET, Android, C++, Go, Lua, ActionScript, ColdFusion, Scala, Clojure, Fantom, CoffeeScript, D, and node.js. If those choices suit your environment, you could script or compile Mustache support to be a command line utility pretty easily.

UPDATE 15-OCT-2013

Now that I've used Mustache for a while -- it's a great tool, simple but powerful.

Comment: I was using the ruby mustache cli, but it seems too simple. At least the docs are.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one: https://gomplate.hairyhenderson.ca
Rich set of functions and just a stanalone binary (written in Go)

Comment: This very one is interesting. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases you can use `envsubst` fom the `gettext` [GNU package](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).
Basically, it reads any (text) file from `stdin`, replaces all occurrences of `$VARIABLE` or `${VARIABLE}` from environment and writes the result to `stdout`. Little more, nothing less.

Full documentation is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html).

**Pros**:

- It is a small binary, no python (or other runtime) required
- It is very fast and has tiny memory footprint

**Cons**:

- It does just that. No special interpolations and functions (like loops, conditionals etc.)
- It doesn't support special `bash`-like "Parameter Expansion"

For more advanced use cases I recommend `j2cli`, a "*standalone*" [Jinja2](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) templating engine you can install from `pip` as it is in Python. Code can be found [here](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli) (*though it looks like a little bit stale...*) and documentation is [there](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli/blob/master/README.md) too.

**Pros**:

- It's Jinja2 with all bells and whistles!

**Cons**:

- You need full Python runtime to run it and PIP to install it.
- Computing resources could not be negligible in constrained environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ESH](https://github.com/jirutka/esh) – a simple templating engine based on shell. It’s written ~290 LoC of POSIX shell and awk.

Example from the project’s readme:

```
http {
    access_log <%= $logs_dir/access.log %> main;

    resolver <%= $(sed -En 's/^nameserver ([^#]+)/\1/p' /etc/resolv.conf) %>;

    <% if nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -q lua-nginx-module; then -%>
    lua_package_path '<%= $(pkg-config --variable=INSTALL_LMOD lua) %>/?.lua';
    <% fi -%>

    <%+ ./http-common.esh %>

    <%# The rest of the config is omitted %>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Ruby on Rails generators are based on a library called [Thor](http://whatisthor.com). It's very useful for creating custom CLI tools for generating code based on templates.